# Laravel middleware verifyCsrfToken set url with variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have a papge require api to post

inside of my route setting is

```
Route::post('/commitmoney/{api}/{payment}', 'CommitmoneyController@post');
```

my problem is in my middleware verifyCsrfToken.php I couldn't set variable like below

```
  protected $except = [
        '/commitmoney/{api}/{payment}',
```

is anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a `*` to make it work, instead of your named parameters:

```
protected $except = [
  '/commitmoney/*/*',
  ...
];
```